# Defining and populating a matrix in Python

Tags: python, matrix

I'm taking a Python class this semester, and my instructor delights in matrices.

My assigned task is as follows:

Create a matrix (x) that is 3 rows, 5 columns.

Populate the matrix using given values loaded from an external file, loading the numbers row-wise (meaning, if you replace the numbers with the order in which they load into the matrix you have:

1, 2, 3

4, 5, 6

7, 8, 9....etc.)

Print the matrix- display it on the screen, and sent the results to an external file.

The given range of numbers is 1,3,5,7,9,0,2,4,6,8,0,1,2,3,4. I have the numbers stored in a file called lab5matrix.dat. The numbers are in the exact same format, commas and all.

The "A" that appears as part of LOADX represents "x". My professor switches up the variables, saying that one doesn't want "too much sugar". I don't have any idea what that means.

When I attempt to run the module i get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "E:/PythonScripts/Lab5-Matrices/lab5matrix.py", line 51, in <module>

    main()

  File "E:/PythonScripts/Lab5-Matrices/lab5matrix.py", line 15, in main

    LOADX(infile, x)

  File "E:/PythonScripts/Lab5-Matrices/lab5matrix.py", line 33, in LOADX

    A[j][k] = int(templist[n])

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Any help is sincerely appreciated.

This is my code, The indentation appears to be accurate:

```
def main():

    #matrix initialization

    x=[[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]


    #file declaration
    infile = open('lab5matrix.dat','r')
    outfile = open('lab5test.out', 'w')
    #call functions
    LOADX(infile, x)

    #close files
    infile.close()
    infile.close()
    outfile.close()
    dummy = input('Press any key to continue.')

#load matrix x
def LOADX(infile, A):
    #local variables
    n=0
    k=0
    s=0
    templist = (infile.readline().strip('\n').split(','))
    while (k<=3):  
        j=0
        while(j<=5):
            A[j][k] = int(templist[n])
            s=s+A[j][k]
            j=j+1
            n=n+1
        k=k+1



def OUTDATA(outfile, A):
    i=0
    j=0
    k=0      
    while (k<3):
        print(A[k][0],A[k][1],A[k][2],A[k][3],A[k][4])
        file.write[str(A[k][0])+str(A[k][1])+str(A[k][2])+str(A[k][3])+str(A[k][3])+str(A[k][4])]
        k=k+1


main()
```

Comment: Please don't use language tags that are not related to your question. Doing so doesn't help you get better or faster answers and will just annoy people, which has a high chance of resulting in your question getting downvotes.

Comment: Welcome to SO! In the future you should only ask questions here once you have tried to solve the problem yourself. Then you can come here and say "Here is my problem, I have tried X, Y, and Z with the following results. What am I doing wrong?" :)

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun :-)

See below for a more Pythonic implementation of the matrix problem. I've only implemented the matrix multiplication because that's the hardest:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

# number of rows and colums for matrix x
NROWSX=5
NCOLSX=3

# number of rows and colums for matrix y
NROWSY=3
NCOLSY=7

# class to hold matrix of any dimension
# and some matrix operations
class Matrix(object):
    def __init__(self, nrows, ncols):
        # define matrix (set dimensions)
        self.nrows = nrows
        self.ncols = ncols

    # create matrix: pass a list and convert it to rows
    def fill(self, values):
        self.matrix = list(self.chunks(values, self.ncols))

    # transpose the matrix
    def transpose(self):
        # serialise matrix data
        __serial = []
        for row in self.matrix:
            __serial += row
        # create new (empty) matrix
        __transp = map(list, [[]] * self.ncols)
        # populate matrix 
        for i in xrange(self.nrows):
            for j in xrange(self.ncols):
                __transp[j].append(__serial[i * self.ncols + j])
        # done
        __new = Matrix(self.ncols, self.nrows)
        __new.matrix = __transp
        return __new

    # helper function to cut up a list in equally sized chunks
    def chunks(self, l, n):
        """Yield successive n-sized chunks from l."""
        for i in xrange(0, len(l), n):
            yield l[i:i+n]

    def __mul__(self, other):
        # our ncols must equal other's nrows for multiplication to work
        if (self.ncols == other.nrows):
            # multiply works best on transposed matrix
            other = other.transpose()
            # execute multiplication serially
            __serial = []
            for r1 in self.matrix:
                for r2 in other.matrix:
                    # calculate sum over row x column
                    s = 0
                    for i in (x*y for x,y in zip(r1,r2)):
                        s += i                    
                    __serial.append(s)
            # turn data into new matrix
            __new = Matrix(self.nrows, other.nrows)
            __new.fill(__serial)
            return __new
        else:
            raise ValueError, "columns and rows don't match"

    def __rmul__(self, other):
        # haven't done this one yet...
        print '__rmul__ not available'
        return None


if __name__ == "__main__":
    datax = [1,3,5,7,9,0,2,4,6,8,0,1,2,3,4] # 5x3
    datay = [6,8,4,0,7,1,2,2,3,7,1,0,1,8,9,6,4,5,7,9,8] # 3x7

    # create and populate matrix x
    mtx_x = Matrix(NROWSX, NCOLSX)
    mtx_x.fill(datax)

    # create and populate matrix y
    mtx_y = Matrix(NROWSY, NCOLSY)
    mtx_y.fill(datay)

    print "\nmatrix x:"
    print mtx_x.matrix

    print "\nmatrix y:"
    print mtx_y.matrix

    # multiply both matrices
    mtx_z = mtx_x * mtx_y

    print "\nmatrix z:"
    print mtx_z.matrix
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this! It makes the statements made in a comment about my solution  make more sense, and gives me an idea of what "grown-up" code looks like!

Answer (score 0):

`A` is a list with 5 elements. So you can only use the numbers 0 to 4 to index it in the function. Note the condition of your inner `while` loop. You are using the values of `j` from 0 to 5. When `j` equals 5 you will run into a problem.

There is a similar problem with the outer `while` loop.

In the future you should try to debug small errors like this. The easiest way to do this is with `print` statements! The error message tells you the error is on `line 33`. It also tells you that there is a list index out of range. So if you simply put `print(j,k,n)` before the error occurs you can determine what exactly is going wrong for yourself :)

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, sorry if I'm not as versed in the etiquette governing this forum as I might be. I'm very new at this particular language- I'm much more proficient in web programming- and while the logic and concepts can be somewhat similar to JavaScript, finding and fixing errors really isn't. Not for me, anyway.

Secondly, the one small question I posted was part of a much larger program that was assigned as a lab...figuring out what I was doing wrong with the X matrix was the Rosetta Stone that helped the whole mess fall into place. I had honestly just gotten to a point where I was just stuck and had no idea what to do. I'm taking this class during summer semester, which is half the length of a regular semester with no fewer assignments or requirements- moving that quickly through this type of material is not conducive to knowledge retention.

A fellow student helped me to get it going...yes, there was a problem with the values in the loop posted above. I fixed that by changing the 'less than or equal to" to just "less than", using all the values up to but not including the value following the operator.

Here's the final (working) X matrix loop:

```
def loadx(file,A):
    #local variable
    k=0
    n=0
    templist=file.readline().strip("\n").split(",")
    while(k<5):
        j=0
        while(j<3):
            A[k][j]=int(templist[n])
            j=j+1
            n=n+1
        k=k+1
```

And, if anyone's interested, I'll post the whole working version of the program- basically, we were given two sets of data, and using these, we wrote a program to load matrix x (5 rows by 3 columns) from a file, loading the values in rows, load matrix y(3 rows, 7 columns) from a file, loading the values in columns, add the sum of column one of the x matrix to the sum of row one of the y matrix, find the smallest value in row 0 of the y matrix, and multiply matrix x by matrix y to generate matrix z, and print the matrices on-screen and write all the results to an outfile.
Simple, right? ; )

```
sumx=0
sumy=0

def main():
    #Matrices declaration
    x=([0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0])
    y=([0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0])
    z=([0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0])
    #file declaration
    infilex=open("lab5x.dat","r")
    infiley=open("lab5y.dat","r")
    outfile=open("lab5.out","w")
    #variable declaration
    totSum=0
    small=0
    #call functions
    loadx(infilex,x)
    loady(infiley,y)
    computez(x,y,z)
    summation(x,y)
    small=float(smallest(y))
    totSum=(sumx+sumy)
    outdata(outfile,x,y,z,small,totSum)
    #close files
    infilex.close()
    infiley.close()
    outfile.close()
    dummy=input("Please press any key to continue")
    #Functions
def loadx(file,A):
    #local variable
    k=0
    n=0
    templist=file.readline().strip("\n").split(",")
    while(k<5):
        j=0
        while(j<3):
            A[k][j]=int(templist[n])
            j=j+1
            n=n+1
        k=k+1
def loady(file,B):
    #local variable
    k=0
    n=0
    templist=file.readline().strip("\n").split(",")
    while(k<7):
        j=0
        while(j<3):
            B[j][k]=int(templist[n])
            j=j+1
            n=n+1
        k=k+1
def computez(A,B,C):
    i=0
    while(i<5):
        j=0
        while(j<7):
            k=0
            while(k<3):
                C[i][j]=C[i][j]+A[i][k]*B[k][j]
                k=k+1
            j=j+1
        i=i+1
def summation(A,B):
    j=0
    k=0
    totSum=0
    #global variable
    global sumx
    global sumy
    while(k<5):
        sumx=A[k][1]+sumx
        k=k+1
    while(j<7):
        sumy=B[1][j]+sumy
        j=j+1
def smallest(B):
    k=0
    small=0
    while(k<7):        
        if small>B[0][k]:
            small=B[0][k]
        k=k+1
    return(small)
def outdata(file,A,B,C,D,E):
    #local variable
    kA=0
    kB=0
    kC=0
    global sumx
    global sumy
    print("OUTPUT", ("\n"))
    print("------")
    print("X Matrix", ("\n"))
    file.write(str("OUTPUT")+"\n")
    file.write("X Matrix"+"\n")
    while (kA<5):
        print("\n")
        j=0
        while(j<3):
            print(A[kA][j])
            file.write(str(A[kA][j])+" ")
            j=j+1
        kA=kA+1
        file.write("\n")
    file.write("\n")
    print("\n")
    print("Y Matrix", ("\n"))
    file.write("Y Matrix"+"\n")
    while(kB<3):
        print("\n")
        j=0
        while(j<7):
            print(B[kB][j]," ")
            file.write(str(B[kB][j])+" ")
            j=j+1
        kB=kB+1
        file.write("\n")
    file.write("\n")
    print("\n")
    print("Z Matrix", ("\n"))
    file.write("Z Matrix"+"\n")
    while (kC<5):
        j=0
        while(j<7):
            print(C[kC][j]," ")
            file.write(str(C[kC][j])+" ")
            j=j+1
        kC=kC+1
        print("\n")
    file.write("\n")
    file.write("Sumx: "+str(sumx)+"\n")
    file.write("Sumy: "+str(sumy)+"\n")
    file.write("Smallest: "+str(D)+"\n")
    file.write("Total Sum: "+str(E))
main()
```

Comment: Good on you for finding a solution. It however contains some first-time mistakes. It is too specific and contains magic numbers: Your functions can only handle matrix sizes as specified in the problem description. Any change in matrix size requires a rewrite of your functions. Better would be to have general functions that can handle any matrix size, where you pass the dimensions as parameters. Magic number are number without meaning. Instead of using 3 in your functions for number of columns you should should use a symbol e.g. NCOLSX=3 for the number of columns of matrix X.

Comment: Thanks! I know my code looks...well, frankly kindergarten-ish, and I do appreciate the helpful hints. I think my teacher really wanted us to get the concepts before bogging us down with too much code detail- a sort of "Fun With Dick and Jane" of Python. I can't wait until I can learn all of the elegant stuff- and I certainly won't be making the mistake of attempting to cram programming classes into the 8 weeks of a summer semester again- I'll be sure to take them during the regular fall or spring that has 16 weeks!

Comment: Programming concepts are indeed very important, more important than the nitty-gritty of a programming language. The strength of Python is its versatility. You can use it as a functional programming language but also object-oriented. This is also its pitfall for people who begin to program. I've been writing software using different programming languages for 35 years now and I'm still learning. Good luck with your next career.